# Spring based Camel Aggregator to read multiple files

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Problem Statement

I have two files File1 and File2 which needs to be parsed using camel Bindy.
The data from File1 and File2 needs to be aggregated and then inserted into database.

what is the best way to define the agregator is there a can somebody provide a sample implementation

Here is what i want

```
<!--route1 -->
<route>
    <from ref="file1Endpoint" />
    <unmarshal ref="pojo1" />
</route>
<!--route2 -->
<route>
    <from ref="file2Endpoint" />
    <unmarshal ref="pojo2" />
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) providing an `Aggregation Strategy`, something like the below:

```
@Component
MyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

   public static final String PRE_ENRICH_KEY = "PRE_ENRICH_KEY";

   //this is meant to be called *before* the actual enrich call
   //to store the state before the enrichment
   public void init(Exchange exchange) {
     final String originalBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
     exchange.setProperty(PRE_ENRICH_KEY, originalBody);
   }

   @Override
  public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange enrichmentResponse) {

    final String originalBody = original.getProperty(PRE_ENRICH_KEY, String.class);

    //enrichmentResponse is the Exchange coming from the 2nd file endpoint
    //the enricher returns

    //your processing logic to merge the 2 happens here
    String result = //..
    original.getIn().setBody(result);

    return original;

  }

}
```

And finally the route will look something like:

```
@Component
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private MyAggregationStrategy myAggregateStrategy;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("fileEndpoint1")
            .bean(myAggregateStrategy, "init")
            .enrich("fileEndpoint2", myMerger);
            //continue from here one to Bindy
    }

    //..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try it in srping DSL way

Comment: @Harish Malavade - if you find this useful please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer